# Why do objects emit color even if they are not under the influence of heat?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, photon-emission

Do correct me if I am wrong:
I am assuming that, when you heat a material, say iron, the electrons gain thermal energy and jump to a higher energy level. When they fall back, they emit photons of particular frequency which strike the retina of our eye, enabling us to perceive color.

Now, when an object is not heated at all, let's take a wooden door for example, how does it emit its brown color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does so by reflection. Light containing all wavelengths (colors) of light falls upon the door surface, and the atoms and molecules there absorb certain of those wavelengths and reflect others. The reflected colors are what your eyes perceive.

Comment: When an object reflects light, it absorbs the rest of the colours (correct me if i am wrong). What happens to the absorbed light?

Comment: the absorbed light heats up the surface slightly.

Answer (score 4):

Objects like your door do not "emit" any visible light. Instead they reflect the light that is coming from a lamp or the sun. If you put the door in total darkness it will be invisible to your eyes - unlike a piece of red-hot iron.

Like all objects, the door does emit electromagnetic radiation as long as its temperature is above absolute zero. However, at normal temperatures that "thermal" radiation is well outside the frequency range to which our eyes are sensitive. Infra-red detectors can "see" the door though.

The spectrum of an object's thermal radiation follows (approximately) the black-body spectrum. [Black body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) consists of all wavelengths, but peaks at a frequency that depends on the object's temperature. When the temperature of an object reaches around 500C that peak is coming into the red end of the visible spectrum, and we can start to see the glow. For your door the peak is in the far-infrared, and almost no visible light is emitted - certainly far too little to be visible.

The same method also gives the stars their colour, from brown dwarfs (mostly infrared) to bright blue "white dwarf" stars. Planets - and your door - however, emit very little visible light, and instead get their colour from reflected sunlight.

The colour of the reflection depends on the colour of the light (in the case of sunlight that is white, a mixture of all the colours of the rainbow) and on what colours the object absorbs. A brown door absorbs mostly blue light, leaving red, green and yellow, which we perceive as brown. Green plants absorb red light, which leaves reflected colours that we see as green.

Comment: Thank you very much. When an object reflects light, it absorbs the rest of the colours (correct me if i am wrong). What happens to the absorbed light?

Comment: Yes, those colours that are not reflected, are absorbed. That imparts energy to the material, which heats it or causes other reactions. As you can tell yourself by standing in the sun, the non-reflected visible and infrared light warm you up, but the absorbed UV light can cause skin cancer by altering the DNA in skin cells.